# Add exception to recurring event using google calendar api in PHP

Tags: php, gdata-api, google-calendar-api

Using the Zend Gdata Calendar classes, how can I add an exception to a recurring event?

```
$orig = $evtFeed[0]; //the original recurrence

$ex = $gc->newEventEntry(); //gc is a Zend_Gdata_Calendar object
$ex->originalEvent = $gc->newOriginalEvent($orig->getId(), $orig->getLink('self')->href, $gc->newWhen('2009-09-23T15:00:00.000Z'));
$ex->eventStatus = $gc->newEventStatus("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.canceled");

$gc->insertEvent($ex);
```

I've tried about 20 variations of the above code but I get the following error every time:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 403 g:originalEvent [2009-09-23 15:00:00] does NOT correspond to an instance of the recurring event.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after hours and hours of searching on the internet, I've come to the conclusion that this may be possible with the zend api, but I will never figure it out. I finally gave up and resorted to editing the recurrence and adding EXDATE rules to the iCalendar data. Thanks to a bug in the google calendar interface, exceptions created this way don't show up unless you refresh the page (the refresh link above the calendar doesn't work) so I wasted even more time.

If anyone finds a way to get this working without resorting to EXDATE please post and I'll be sure to check back periodically and mark the correct answer.

**UPDATE:** Ok I figured it out. I'm going to blame this one partially on me being an idiot and partially on Google's horrible naming system. Calling `getId()` on an `EventEntry` actually returns the event's EDIT URL. The `OriginalEvent` constructor expects only the actual ID portion of the URL so you must use substring to extract it. How nice of them to name the `getId()` accessor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse getId, just use calendarEventEntry.getIcalUID().

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Parsing getId() works fine, however.